# How to call the @Load annotation in a a Class that is itself a Ref<?> Objectify in GAE java

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have 2 classes

```
@Entity 
Class Content{
@Id Long id;
 String title;
@Load(ArtisteLoadGroup.class) Ref<Artiste> artiste;
public class ArtisteLoadGroup{}
 }
```

and

```
@Entity 
Class Featured{
@Id Long id;
 String name;
@Load Ref<Content> content;
 }
```

When query datastore

```
Query<Featured> query = OfyService.ofy().load().group(ArtisteLoadGroup.class)
                        .type(Featured.class).filter("name", "bell");
QueryResultIterator<Featured> iterator = query.iterator();
```

When i display the result, the content is loaded but the artiste is not loaded.What can I do to make the artiste load?

Comment: Looks like it should work fine. Are you sure the entity being loaded exists?

Comment: Yes, It exist, as I said content is loaded but the artiste Ref is not loaded from datastore.

Comment: There is something more going on here that is not apparent from the included code. Try to distill this down to a minimal test case. There are tests for the transitivity of load groups.

Answer (score -1):

If i remove the ArtisteLoadGroup, the artiste loads up correctly for the query.

```
Entity 
Class Content{
@Id Long id;
 String title;
@Load Ref<Artiste> artiste;

 }
```

You cannot have controlled loading in a nested @Load using load groups.

Comment: This is incorrect. Load groups transitively load, see: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/test/java/com/googlecode/objectify/test/LoadGroupTransitiveTest.java